# DataGrid Repeated Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm creating a WPF View with a `DataGrid`.

The `DataGrid` is bound to the field `Properties` on the `ViewModel`.

However, for one of the columns I want each row to have the same value bound to some other property on the View model.

Specificically, the table is showing named monetary values and the repeated column will show a currency code (which is the same for each row).

I can't figure out how to do this, I've tried to use the following:

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Target" Binding="{Binding Target}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Currency">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Properties.NodeCurrency}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

I'm using the Caliburn framework with no typed `DataContext` in the View. I'm not sure if this matters to the question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With assistance from both answerers the actual binding I needed was:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Property.NodeCurrency, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

The missing bit was specifying that I'm binding to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` and then delving down into the properties on the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it via RelativeSource of Binding. For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Property.NodeCurrency, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, the View is implemented as a UserControl - possibly because it's part of a larger window. I've tried using a relative source with both Window and UserControl and the column remains blank.

Comment: @Nick Try `DataGrid`. Have you some error logged in the output window ?

Comment: Ok, it turns out I need to specify the DataContext of the UserControl in the Binding Path. E.g. {Binding DataContext.Property.NodeCurrency}

Comment: Yes, Path should starts with DataContext

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeSource/FindAncestor on your binding to bind to an other DataContext than the current one :

```
<TextBlock
   Text="{Binding Property.NodeCurrency, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```